# CSS Z-index not overlapping

Tags: css, z-index, overlap

So I was trying to customize a website with CSS but I cannot overlap [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRgpO.jpg) under [this element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgOna.jpg).
The code:

```
body#bodyDefault > form > div > table > tbody::after {
    pointer-events: none;
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    background-image: url('');
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-size: 200px;
}
body#bodyDefault > form > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) {
    z-index: 50;
}
```

I am trying to cut the excessive part of the image by hiding it under the tr element.

Comment: can you share your code

Comment: what you tried? for ti can you share then we'll fixed.

Comment: i added the code

Comment: can you show your html also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use  `position: absolute/relative;` to `body#bodyDefault > form > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2)`**

*why?*

`z-index` does not work without `position: absolute/relative;`

**For example:**

```
body#bodyDefault > form > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) {
    z-index: 50;
    position: absolute;// or relative
}
```